# Do any advaita vedanta Sutra discribe heaven?

Tags: vedanta, advaita

Do any advaita vedanta Sutra describes heaven and it pleasure?

Do advaita vedanta believes that heaven is a state of mind or do they believe that heaven is a physical place some  were in the universe .
Where we can live and eat the best food , drink all kinds of drink.

Comment: You should always try to give a prologue/preface to your question. One liner question are generally to be avoided. Try explaining the doubt a bit.

Comment: @Vivikta I have edited it.